# Проверка формы в реальном времени

Tags: javascript

Есть форма с полем input, и кнопка button. Нужно при вводе к примеру 0 кнопка исчезала, а при вводе 1 кнопка появлялась в режиме реального времени без обновления страницы. Я знаю, что нужно использовать JQuery, но ничего пока не получается. Может кто знает какой-нибудь пример?

Comment: Добавьте код в вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('input').on('input', function() {
    switch (this.value) {
      case '0': $('button').hide(); break;
      case '1': $('button').show(); break;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input/>
<button>Click</button>
```